# How to pass in custom data to branch.io SDK banner init() call

Tags: branch.io

I have a branch smart banner running on my web app using the branch SDK, and I would like to pass in some custom data that will be able to be retrieved when the user downloads our app via the smart banner.

Is there a way to pass in this custom data into the branch.init call?

maybe something like this?

```
const data = {
  custom: 'foo'
}

branch.init(BRANCH_KEY, data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set deep link data, like so:

`branch.setBranchViewData({
    data: {
        '$deeplink_path': 'picture/12345',
        'picture_id': '12345',
        'user_id': '45123'
    }
});`

This is only required if custom key-value pairs are used. With Canonical URL, Branch handles this at its end.

For more information, please reference our documentation here: https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/journeys/#deep-linking-from-the-banner-or-interstitial